# split tuple of dict into individual records in dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dataframe df.  It has a column with data in it like the example below.  Each record contains a tuple in the column of dicts that have been identified as a "match".  I would like to create a new dataframe from the df match column like the output below.  Where I split the tuple in to individual records and each of their keys in to columns, adding a "type" field with value "a" to indicate that the two records were matched.  Also I want to add an TypeId field so each tuple has an id number to identify that the matched values came from the same original record.  Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

code:

```
df['match'][0]
```

data:

```
{'__class__': 'tuple',
 '__value__': [{'': '363336',
   'unitofmeasure': 'each',
   'product_id': '11',
   'classification': 'top',
   'Id': '363336'},
  {'': '368654',
   'unitofmeasure': 'each',
   'product_id': '10',
   'classification': 'bottom',
   'Id': '368654'}]}
```

output:

```
        unitofmeasure  product_id  classification  Id      type  typeId
363336  each           11          top             363336  a     1
368654  each           10          bottom          368654  a     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# read record in from match

emptLst=[]

for i in range(len(df['match'].dropna())):


    df2=pd.DataFrame(df['match'][i]['__value__'])

    # add match column with value 'a'

    df2['label']='a'

    # df2.head()

    # add column id value based on row number from original dataframe

    df2['labeling_set_id']=i

    emptLst.append(df2)


for j in range(len(emptLst)):

    if j==0:
        dfm=emptLst[0]

    else:

        dfm=pd.concat([dfm,emptLst[j]])


# read record in from distinct

emptLst2=[]

for i in range(len(df['distinct'].dropna())):


    df3=pd.DataFrame(df['distinct'][i]['__value__'])

    # add label column with value 'b'

    df3['label']='b'

    # df3.head()

    # add column id value based on row number from original dataframe

    df3['labeling_set_id']=(i+len(df['distinct'].dropna()))

    emptLst2.append(df3)


for j in range(len(emptLst2)):

    if j==0:
        dfd=emptLst2[0]

    else:

        dfd=pd.concat([dfd,emptLst2[j]])


df_label=pd.concat([dfm,dfd])

df_label['labeling_set_id']=df_label['labeling_set_id']+1

df_label.head()
```